# C++ Reference for Programmer Returning from Java

Tags: java, c++

Here's my situation: I taught myself C++ (albeit rather badly), and was later taught how to use Java in college. Returning to C++, I find myself confused by several things that differ from C++ to Java, for example memory management and avoiding memory leaks.

What would be the best mode of returning to programming in C++? Should I read a beginner's guide again, or are there some good references for my kind of situation?

All help is appreciated and thanks!

Comment: The biggest difference is that Java has a automatic garbage collection, while C++ does not. You must ensure that every object in C++ has its own destructor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you never **properly** learned C++ (you say you learned it "badly"), start over. Forget everything about Java, because trying to use Java idioms and techniques in C++ is just a recipe for bugs and memory leaks and very inefficient code. The differences between the languages are fairly big.

So get a good book teaching C++ from scratch.

Comment: +1, C++ and Java are as different as a Lunar night from a Venusian day.

Comment: This book makes no real recommendation on *what* text to choose. Doesn't get to the heart of the question, IMO - so i downvote.

Comment: I didn't ask for a book recommendation, I asked for a strategy, @jdt. This answer is the most upvoted because it gives a good strategy and explains why it's a good strategy.

Comment: Oh ok I misinterpreted. "C++ reference", to me, means a book, website, or some other outstanding body of knowlegde. Whatever works for you, my friend!

Answer (score 8):

There are books especially for your desire, check out:
C++ for Java programmers by [Mark Allen Weiss](http://books.google.com/books?id=rliaQgAACAAJ&dq=c%2B%2B+for+java+programmer&hl=en&ei=HrVQTKfRNcq6OKT8gIgI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg), or by [Timothy Budd](http://books.google.com/books?id=DbJQAAAAMAAJ&q=c%2B%2B+for+java+programmer&dq=c%2B%2B+for+java+programmer&hl=en&ei=HrVQTKfRNcq6OKT8gIgI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA).

Here are some links:

- [Moving from Java to C++](http://www.horstmann.com/ccj2/ccjapp3.html)
- [C++ for Java Programmers](http://www.ittybittycomputers.com/Courses/Prior/ADS/C4Java.htm)

Comment: I wouldn't say that, for each is own pov. anyway I changed the link.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata.  A bit dry, but very focused.

You might also want to consider The C++ Standard Library by Nicolai M. Josuttis

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the basics of C++ then I would recommend reading [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) by Scott Meyers.   It contains a wealth of tips and guidelines for writing better C++ code.  Unlike previous editions, the third edition of the book was revised to take into account that readers were coming from backgrounds other than C coding (Java being one of those).

Chapter 3 of the book deals with Resource Management, including how to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I love Scott's books, but I would not recommend them for anybody unless they already have a fairly good grasp of C++. The recommendations are based on explaining in details why things should be done. Nearly all these explanations are way beyond the casual C++ user.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to start from the scratch. There are already lot of answers holding good books with it. Follow any one of those, though I myself liked `C++ Primer`.

And for your question

> What would be the best mode of
>   returning to programming in C++?

IMO there is only one mode. It is **Practice, practice, practice.**

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best I've used. Explains how its not C, or "C with Classes".

[Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html)